# iPhone Visual Voicemail with Twilio Programmable Wireless

Tags: twilio

If one were to use the Twilio Programmable Wireless individual metering plan with an unlocked iPhone, would it be possible to configure it in such a way as to have recordings display as voicemails through the native iOS "phone" app in the visual voicemails section?

I understand one could just build their own visual voicemail app for Twilio recordings, but I'm curious if it would be possible to integrate with the native visual voicemails functionality on iPhone, the same way traditional carriers do.

Answer (score 0):

We do not currently support VVM but you have full control over the call flow via the API:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/wireless/rest-api

So like you say, you could record voicemails and do whatever you want with them just not present them in the standard VVM iOS UI.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

Visual Voicemail is just IMAP with some custom extensions (for setting the initial greeting, etc), and the IMAP details (server, username & password) are sent to the device by SMS.

Please take a look at the [specification](http://www.omtp.org/OMTP_VVM_Specification_v1_3_Final.pdf).